# Finding the ordinate of a point using some conditions

Tags: coordinate-systems

[image: This is the question] My solution:-

Since $OA=AB$, let us find OA first.
$OA=\sqrt{(18-0)^2+(3-0)^2}=3\sqrt{37}$. So, $AB=3\sqrt{37}$. So,
$$\sqrt{(15-18)^2+(k-3)^2}=3\sqrt{37}$$
$$\implies(-3)^2+(k-3)^2=333$$
$$\implies k^2-6k+9=324$$
$$\implies k^2-6k-315=0$$
$Using\\calculator$
$$k=21$$ or, $$k=-15$$

Is my solution correct?

I'm asking this because my book only mentions k=21 but not k=-15. But I don't find k=-15 to be an extraneous root as the equation holds true using -15 as the solution as well. So will the answer be both 21 and -15 or only -15?

If there's any problem in my question please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is another condition $\angle{OAB}=90^\circ$.

Comment: @mathlove Not required as abscissa is already given.

Comment: FYI, I would guess the intended method of solution is to simply make use of slope conditions, which is usually covered in school before distance formula. Since $\overline{AO}$ and $\overline{AB}$ are perpendicular, their slopes must be negative reciprocals of each other. This leads to $\frac{k-3}{15-18}=-\left(\frac{3-0}{18-0}\right)^{-1},$ or $\frac{k-3}{-3}=-\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{-1} = -6.$ Multiplying both sides of the last equation by $-3$ gives $k-3=(-6)(-3)=18,$ and therefore $k=18+3=21.$ Of course, this doesn't answer your question, which I think is quite reasonable by the way (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph shows several explicit-implicit conditions. One of them is the angle $\angle OAB=90^\circ$. Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

Note that $\angle OAC\ne 90^\circ$.

Also note that just because the point $B$ is in the first quadrant does not automatically imply the second root is extraneous. If the whole graph is shifted over $15$ units upward, the point $C$ (or the second root) will also be in the first quadrant, but then it must be ignored by the condition of the right angle.

Answer (score 1):

Since the point is shown in first quadrant, so $k=-15$ is ignored.

Another method is by using complex numbers, since multiplication by $i$ is anticlockwise rotation by $90°$, we can write coordinates of $B$ as $$18+3i+i(18+3i)$$
$$=15+21i$$
$$\implies k=21$$